# How to handle a project with multiple tsconfig.json files?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I'm working on a project structured like this:

```
\
|- built
|- src
|- perf
   |- tsconfig.json
|- typings
|- tsconfig.json
```

My `tsconfig.json` on the root

```
"target": "es6",
"outDir": "built",
"rootDir": "./src",
```

I need a different configuration on the `perf` folder, like a different target.

```
"target": "es5",
```

However, my `typings` folder is on the root of my project, not inside `perf` folder. So doing a `tsc ./perf` results in a lot of errors.

Is there a way to tell TypeScript where to look for `typings`? I'm using

```
npm install -g typescript@next
// typescript@1.8.0-dev.20151109
```

Or a way to have different configurations depending on the folder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use multiple tsconfig files in vs-code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579969/how-to-use-multiple-tsconfig-files-in-vs-code)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use multiple tsconfig files (with conflicting compiler options)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611311/how-to-use-multiple-tsconfig-files-with-conflicting-compiler-options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell TypeScript where to look for typings

## Quickest solution

Move `typings` into pref.

## Long term solution

Use `filesGlob` once it is supported in `tsc` : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1927

Answer (score 9):

you can do this by extending your base tsconfig.json file:

[tsconfig extension](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#configuration-inheritance-with-extends)

just do not exclude directories in the base tsconfig.json and typescript should be able to resolve your typings for you (know this is true using node_modules/@types, or the typings module)

For example:

configs/base.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./configs/base",
  "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "supplemental.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.nostrictnull.json:

```
{
   "extends": "./tsconfig",
   "compilerOptions": {
     "strictNullChecks": false
   }
}
```

Comment: Link-only answers are not useful when the content changes or is removed. Include the relevant parts of the page in your answer, tailored to answer the question.

Comment: That is unrecognizable. That means I can't have multiple tsconfigs.