# How can I specify multiple source folders in my tsconfig.json?

Tags: unit-testing, typescript

I currently have the following project structure:

```
project/
  tsconfig.json
  webpack.config.js
  package.json
  node_modules/
    ...lots of dependencies
  typings/
    ...lots of .d.ts files for the dependencies
  src/
    ...folders for files for my projects
```

My `tsonfig.json` looks like:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "./js",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react"
},
"exclude": [
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typings/main",
    "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

This all works very well and I can happily develop my application and run it in a browser.

I would now like to add some unit tests to my project and coming from a Java background my initial instinct is to place the tests in a separate folder:

```
project/
  test/
    ...all of my test cases
```

Of course, the files in the `test/` folder need to reference the code in my `src/` folder. How do I set that up?

Or is it "better" to place the tests inline in the `src/` folder and have a separate `webpack.config.js` file for them?

Really confused about how this works in practice in larger TypeScript projects.

Note: I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33618741/how-to-handle-a-project-with-multiple-tsconfig-json-files) but found the answer less than illuminating. It seems that the referenced feature discussion about `filesGlob` would help me, but I just wonder how people are doing this today?

Answer (score 17):

Now other than `rootDir`, you can use `rootDirs`

```
"rootDirs": ["./scripts", "./src"],
```

for multiple folders.

Here is the API doc: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#virtual-directories-with-rootdirs

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for path mapping. With the `paths` compiler option, you can specify not only a mapping to a single location but to several. This is the example from [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html):

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "*",
        "generated/*"
      ]
    }
}
```

If the compiler does not find a module in the expected location, it repeats module resolution in the "generated" subfolder. The `baseUrl` setting seems redundant but it is mandatory.

Comment: Thanks for this. We have settled on using `jest` for running the tests with `ts-jest` and keeping them inline in the `src/` folder. Works very well for us.

Answer (score 1):

> Or is it "better" to place the tests inline in the src/ folder and have a separate webpack.config.js file for them?

That is what I do. Do not use the TypeScript compiler as a module bundler (Especially if you are not using modules https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md). Just let it do the compile and bundle for browser using webpack and use as it is (if using module commonjs) for backend (nodejs).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using webpack for bundling. For now I only have client code (the server is an existing Java one). When running the tests, do you actually run webpack and bundle a complete .js file, or is there some fancy webpack mode like the webpack-dev-server which does it all in memory?

Comment: All in memory. See https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/ and https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/blob/master/docs/contributing/README.md#webpack

Comment: alm looks amazing, however it does not install on my Windows 7 machine ("npm install" fails during prepublish - looks like you are expecting me to have bash, but this is not mentioned as a prerequisite). In addition, it is not clear to me how this would enable me to bundle and run my tests in memory.