# Start to use 'strict' in tsconfig

Tags: typescript

I have this `tsconfig.json` file

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2019",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./src/types"
    ],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "pretty": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "allowJs": true,
    "noEmit": false
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "tests"
  ]
}
```

As far as you can see there are no strict rules there. The most important for me it's starting to use `strictNullChecks` setting, but my project is already large, and when I set this setting to `true` I've got ~1000 errors.

I want to start refactor code for avoiding potential issues, but I want to move step by step, file by file and don't want to spend time resolving 1000 errors at once.

How can I achieve it?
I had a plan to use a comment `// @ts-ignore` for each error line and then incrementally resolve problems. But it's even hard to add `// @ts-ignore` 1000 times. How can I do it automatically?
Any advice please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one approach was using multiple `tsconfig.json` files. Start adding them at the "leaves" and move them further up the hierarchy as the stricter types get added. These files can be based on a root config using [`"extends"`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#extends). Using multiple configs [apparently can be tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579969/how-to-use-multiple-tsconfig-files-in-vs-code), though.

If this does not work you can add just one config and manually list files that have been migrated; the [VS Code team did this](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/05/23/strict-null#_coming-up-with-an-incremental-plan).

```js
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json", // Shared configuration with our main `tsconfig.json`
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noEmit": true, // Don't output any javascript
        "strictNullChecks": true
    },
    "files": [
        // Slowly growing list of strict null check files goes here
    ]
}
```