# How to include a typescript file for files in specific folder without import?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Somehow I need to include a d.ts file for every files in a specify folder while not polluting other files' global namespace, how can I achieve this without import(there is lots of typing in that d.ts) or triple slash(this is disabled by eslint)?

It imports some typing from dependencies so simply include it won't have any effect

Comment: Does it mean that you don't wanna use tree-shaking?

Comment: it's pure type so I don't think that has anything to do with tree shaking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `tsconfig.json`, you can add the `include` property and add a reference to the files you want included. E.g.

```
"include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./definitions/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
```

This is not going to create a dependency, or import the file in your project, but will look for the types inside it, same way as the triple slash method.

Comment: You should be able to create [sub-`tsconfig.json` for subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33618741/how-to-handle-a-project-with-multiple-tsconfig-json-files/41860128#41860128) with the above code in it. This seems like the most correct answer you'll get.

Comment: @P.Moloney maybe that's the only solution. Make an answer, you deserve the reputation

Answer (score 0):

Best practice to do this is define `typeRoots` property in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"typeRoots": [
  "src/@types",
  "node_modules/@types"
]
```

And in `src/@types` directory add custom `.d.ts` files look like below:

```
// in src/@types/scss.d.ts
declare module '*.scss' {
  const styles: { [className: string]: string };
  export default styles;
}
```